# How to delete a row in uigrid if the button is outside of the grid

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, meteor, angular-ui-grid

I had a uigrid. It had a edit button in each row. When I click that, a button will be displayed outside of uigrid. When I click that button, the particular row should be deleted. If the button is with in the grid row, I am able to delete. But if it's outside of grid am not able to. How can we delete so?

```
Here is the plunker:
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/QWdPUCVpK4UV2CQcX4n0?p=preview

Comment: Please don't use code formatting on non-code just to get around the code requirement. Would you repair this by editing into your post a good representation of the relevant code in the question itself?

Comment: haha..But my code is too big and it may require additional files and may not run in plunker.It may take very long..This example meets to my requirement ..so to savetime i used that

Comment: It doesn't meet our requirements though, unfortunately! Our experience is that external links die off quickly, and a major aim of Stack Overflow is to collect questions and answers that will survive into the long term. Once external links return 404, we have to delete the question containing the link, unless there is enough information within for it to remain understandable.

Comment: Your problem is not clear to me. Could you try to put more effort into the plunker to reflect your issue in more detail?

Answer (score 1):

As i understand correctly u need delete functionality outside the grid. So you can delete selected row when user click on delete button which is outside of the grid.

I tried based on my understanding **[HERE](http://plnkr.co/edit/8URgcK5J1QpwaKo3cHfK?p=preview)** is updated plunker.

```
$scope.rowToRemove=null;

  $scope.editRow = function(row){
    $scope.rowToRemove = row;
    $scope.button = true;
  };

  $scope.deleteRow = function() {
    console.log($scope.rowToRemove);
    var index = $scope.gridOptions.data.indexOf($scope.rowToRemove.entity);
    $scope.gridOptions.data.splice(index, 1);
    $scope.button = false;
  };
```